# Connect and Lex to get DTMF input and store as contact attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex, amazon-connect

trying to set up a contact flow which will invoke a lex bot to play a prompt and capture a DTMF input. I want this DTMF input to be stored as a contact attribute to be returned to a Lambda later on in the flow.

Is this possible and it creating an intent/slots specifically just for this necessary?

Comment: Why do you have to use Lex?

Comment: I wanted to use Lex because session attributes would give me more control over various things. For example some prompts in the flow will or won’t be interruptible, and a Lambda triggered before hitting the Lex bot will pass it a Boolean to confirm if it’s interruptible . The bool is used in the Lex session attribute x-amz-lex:allow-interrupt:*:*. 

Get/Store customer input are more restricted in that regard.